# Angular 4 Error: while sending http request to node through IP address: Err connection refused

Tags: angular, httprequest, ip-address, connection-timeout

I am sending an Angular http IP Request to Node and getting an Error: **net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**.
Code was working good from last 1 month and suddenly it broke. i am able to send request through localhost and other external Api's and all working good except the IP Address Request.
I already crosschecked the portNo and the Ip that i am sending request and everything seems to be correct.

Can Anyone help me out here.!! This is very weird Situation for me.

Attached the error and some code. let me know if you need anything else.

//in my addPropertyService service:

```
getDetails() {

    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authToken': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh'
    });

    return this.http.get('http://172.16.10.68:8080/api/property', { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            console.log('Response in service: ', result);
            return result;
        })

}
```

//in componenet

```
onSearch(){
this.addPropertyService.getDetails()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.Data = data;
            })
}
```

[myConsole Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NSVN.png)

Comment: this uri doesn't return any response, you can check this getting the error: onSearch(){
this.addPropertyService.getDetails()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.Data = data;
            }, (err) => { console.log(err.status)})
}

Comment: The problem is in your api server, not the angular app

Comment: IT's possible your API not work propertly (effectively take too much time -a infinite loop, an user intervention mush be required, etc.-) or your port is bloqued by a firewall, or your IP adress it's not correct.